# Rebasing a branch changing contents of a newly added file which has no conflicts

Tags: git, github

Is there an instance where when rebasing a branch with let's say `origin master` results in contents of a newly created file (that has no conflicts since it's new) in that branch changing? If so, what could be the reason for that?

I had three commits on the branch I was rebasing with origin master. I began by checking out a new branch for my new work and added content in a newly created file on the new branch then committed those changes, first-commit, I added more content to the same file and committed second-commit, then I added more content to the same file and committed again third-commit, hence the three commits. So when I tried to rebase, the HEAD went to the first-commit I made and so the contents of the file changed to how it was on the first commit, so when I finished rebasing, the other two commits second-commit and third-commit were replayed on top and my file contents were as they were before I began the rebase.

I'm not sure whether git goes to the first commit on a branch when rebasing that branch and hides the rest of the commits on that branch until the rebase is done.

Comment: Hi, Richard. Your situation is not clear to me. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Does `origin/master` also introduce the file between where the branch was originally based and the current tip of `origin/master`?  If the content is the same when it was first created, then yes, it's possible that it can introduce some changes that you didn't have in your original branch.  But without concrete details, it's hard to debug your situation.

Comment: Thanks, @Schwern I think I found out why but not sure whether I'm right, I posted in the answer block since the comment box is limited for my detailed explanation, I would like to know whether I'm right

Answer (score 0):

When rebasing git replays the commit one by one. It's important to understand that it's commits one by one, not file one by one.

> I'm not sure whether git goes to the first commit on a branch when rebasing that branch and hides the rest of the commits on that branch until the rebase is done.

Yes that's what happens. This is so that you can do the merge in each commit separately.

Here's a bit more about rebasing [atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase).

Here is a little scenario

```
>git init repo666
Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/c/git/repo666/.git/
>cd repo666/
(master)>echo 'Hello World!' > a.txt
(master)>cat a.txt
Hello World!
(master)>git add a.txt
 (master)>git commit -m "1st commit in master"
[master (root-commit) 3c088b8] 1st commit in master
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
(master)>git checkout -b branch_b
Switched to a new branch 'branch_b'
(branch_b)>echo 'Bees are best (1)' > b.txt
(branch_b)>git add b.txt
  (branch_b)>git commit -m "1st commit in branch b"
[branch_b 1380e52] 1st commit in branch b
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 b.txt
(branch_b)>echo 'Bees are best (2)' >> b.txt
(branch_b)>git commit -am "2nd commit in branch b"
   [branch_b 3cd723d] 2nd commit in branch b
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
(branch_b)>echo "I'm being changed in branch b!" > a.txt
(branch_b)>echo "I'm b.txt and I'm being changed in the same commit with a.txt (in branch b)" > b.txt
(branch_b)>git commit -am "3rd commit in branch b, changed both a.txt and b.txt"
   [branch_b 5864038] 3rd commit in branch b, changed both a.txt and b.txt
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
(branch_b)>echo "Bees are best again" > b.txt
(branch_b)>git commit -am "4th commit in branch b. b.txt has changed again"
  [branch_b e32af63] 4th commit in branch b. b.txt has changed again
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
(branch_b)>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
(master)>echo "I'm being changed in the 2nd commit in master" > a.txt
(master)>git commit -am "2nd commit in master. Changed a.txt"
 [master f2849fc] 2nd commit in master. Changed a.txt
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Let's look at our history.

```
(master)>git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --reverse
3c088b8 1st commit in master
f2849fc (HEAD -> master) 2nd commit in master. Changed a.txt
```

```
(master)>git checkout branch_b
Switched to branch 'branch_b'
(branch_b)>git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --reverse
3c088b8 1st commit in master
1380e52 1st commit in branch b
3cd723d 2nd commit in branch b
5864038 3rd commit in branch b, changed both a.txt and b.txt
e32af63 (HEAD -> branch_b) 4th commit in branch b. b.txt has changed again
```

```
(branch_b)>git rebase --interactive master
Auto-merging a.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a.txt
error: could not apply 5864038... 3rd commit in branch b, changed both a.txt and b.txt

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".

Could not apply 5864038... 3rd commit in branch b, changed both a.txt and b.txt
```

Now if we look at b.txt the content is from the 3rd (not 4th) commit in branch b.

```
(branch_b|REBASE-i 3/4)>cat b.txt
I'm b.txt and I'm being changed in the same commit with a.txt (in branch b)
(branch_b|REBASE-i 3/4)>
```

If we continue with the rebase the changes to `b.txt` in 4th commit will be applied.